# Missing series name as label in highcharts heatmaps

Tags: highcharts

I created a calendar using a heatmap, like this:

calendar screen:

[image]

The axis types are categories, so the months are placed as blocks with the respective offset in the matrix. Every month is defined as a series with names.

Now my problem is, I want to show the month name above the block. However, I found no way to display the serial name. He is simply ignored.
The x-axis displays only the index of the category. I can not use this. The data label contains the color value for the heatmap.
My workaround currently is that I insert the month names as PlotLine. But that's not the way to go. Especially since the positioning is independent of the monthly block and thus error-prone.

```
series: [{
    name: 'January',
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'value'],
    data: [...]
}, ...next month...]
```

[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/xreality/410t5a8j/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` to add series name as text in calculated position:

```
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series = this.series,
                bbox;

            series.forEach(function(s) {
                bbox = s.group.getBBox(true);
                this.renderer.text(
                        s.name,
                        bbox.x + this.plotLeft + bbox.width/2,
                        bbox.y + this.plotTop - 10
                    )
                    .attr({
                        align: 'center'
                    })
                    .css({
                        color: 'black',
                        fontSize: '12px'
                    })
                    .add();
            }, this);
        }
    }
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zypnwq50/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#text

Comment: That's right, I've already thought of that. I did not know how.
Perfect. Many Thanks
Maik